# Python Key Error filtering MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pdf

So I have a little program which makes a DB call and then converts it into a PDF. 
I have most of them working but this last one is returning a Key Error on me and I cannot figure out why.

Here is an example of the data being returned by the DB:

```
((None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0, 26), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 18), (2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 16))
```

The Traceback: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\Ace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Ace/Desktop/IPNV/KP_App/FML/firstapp.py", line 232, in hrday_in
    hourday_filter(noodle, dest, drange)
  File "C:\Users\Ace\Desktop\IPNV\KP_App\FML\dataIN.py", line 187, in hourday_filter
    doc.export(pths, drange)
  File "C:\Users\Ace\Desktop\IPNV\KP_App\FML\calazan.py", line 58, in export
    reverse=reverse_order)
KeyError: 'h'
```

Im not even sure where the 'h' comes from.

Here is the function that I run the data through to prepare for the pdf generation:

```
def hourday_filter(tuna, pth, drange):
    data = []
    for hr, number, local, chicken, alligator, ace, lola, chunk in tuna:
        data.append({'hour': hr,
                     'number': number,
                     'local': local,
                     'long': chicken,
                     'inter': alligator,
                     'income': ace,
                     'tandem': lola,
                     'total': chunk})

    fields = (
        ('hour', 'Hour of Day'),
        ('number', 'Internal Calls '),
        ('local', 'Local Calls'),
        ('long', 'Long Distance Calls'),
        ('inter', 'International Calls '),
        ('income', 'Incoming Calls'),
        ('tandem', 'Tandem Calls'),
        ('total', 'Total Calls'),
    )

    pths = pth + '/HourofDay.pdf'
    doc = DataToPdf(fields, data, sort_by='hr',
                    title='Hour of Day Report')
    doc.export(pths, drange)
```

And From there the data is passed to this function to actually convert it too pdf.

```
class DataToPdf:
    """
    Export a list of dictionaries to a table in a PDF file.
    """
    def __init__(self, fields, data, sort_by=None, title=None):
        """
        Arguments:
            fields - A tuple of tuples ((fieldname/key, display_name))
                specifying the fieldname/key and corresponding display
                name for the table header.
            data - The data to insert to the table formatted as a list of
                dictionaries.
            sort_by - A tuple (sort_key, sort_order) specifying which field
                to sort by and the sort order ('ASC', 'DESC').
            title - The title to display at the beginning of the document.
        """
        self.fields = fields
        self.data = data
        self.title = title
        self.sort_by = sort_by

    def export(self, filename, drange, data_align='LEFT', table_halign='LEFT'):
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(filename, pagesize=letter)
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        styleH = styles['Heading1']
        styleD = styles['Heading4']
        date = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        date2 = 'Ran on: ' + date
        date3 = ' For the period  ' + str(drange[0]) + ' to ' + str(drange[1])  # Edit here to display report date range
        story = []
        if self.title:
            story.append(Paragraph(self.title, styleH))
            story.append(Spacer(1, 0.25 * inch))
            story.append(Paragraph(date2, styleD))
            story.append(Spacer(1, 0.015 * inch))
            story.append(Paragraph(date3, styleD))

        if self.sort_by:
            reverse_order = False
            if str(self.sort_by[1]).upper() == 'DESC':
                reverse_order = False

            self.data = sorted(self.data,
                               key=itemgetter(self.sort_by[0]),
                               reverse=reverse_order)

        converted_data = self.__convert_data()
        table = Table(converted_data, hAlign=table_halign)
        table.setStyle(TableStyle([
            ('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),
            ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'CENTER'),
            ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (0, -1), data_align),
            ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.50, colors.black),
            ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
        ]))

        data_len = len(converted_data)

        for each in range(data_len):
            if each % 2 == 0:
                bg_color = colors.whitesmoke
            else:
                bg_color = colors.lightgrey

            table.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND', (0, each), (-1, each), bg_color)]))

        story.append(table)
        doc.build(story)

    def __convert_data(self):
        """
        Convert the list of dictionaries to a list of list to create
        the PDF table.
        """
        # Create 2 separate lists in the same order: one for the
        # list of keys and the other for the names to display in the
        # table header.
        keys, names = zip(*[[k, n] for k, n in self.fields])
        new_data = [names]

        for d in self.data:
            new_data.append([d[k] for k in keys])

        return new_data
```

Is it possible that first result of the db (the null one) is causing this? I've made about a dozen of these reports now with no problems, not sure where I am messing up here.

Comment: I think the `h` comes from where you do `self.sort_by[0]` in the `sorted` function call where `self.sort_by` is `'hr'`. Was `sort_by` a tuple at some point?

Comment: It shouldn't have been. The data example I posted is what should be getting passed to the call

Comment: I removed the 'sort_by' parameter from the hour_day() filter and now it is printing! kind of. didnt quite fit into the page but that is a horse of a different color. Do you know why that was breaking it?

Comment: The `sort_by` parameter either needs to be a tuple or you need to update the `DataToPdf.export` code from `self.sort_by[0]` to `self.sort_by`. By not passing anything,  that part of the code is skipped. Also, you are passing `'hr'` as the `sort_by` argument,
 which should be `'hour'` I am pretty sure.

Comment: I tried it as hour and received that same error. So was the sort_by[0] getting hung up on the Null field ?

Comment: No, the `sort_by` parameter either needs to be a tuple or you need to update the `DataToPdf.export` code from `self.sort_by[0]` to `self.sort_by`. That is where the problem is. Fix that.

Comment: Made that change and got this `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType`  Its ok though as long as I have it working some way. Thank you. If you post it as an answer I will mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to FamousJameous I realized that it was indeed the first field killing my filter. The sort_by call did not know how to deal with the NULL value. I managed to fix it by removing that first field from the tuple.

The database returned the results into the variable `result`
From there:
`new_result = result[1:]`
This line removed the NULL line and stopped the error